# OData - reading metadata and querying data without service reference

Tags: c#, rest, odata

I am creating a generic data reader, able to connect to a catalogue that defines SQL and OData endpoints.

For OData - Given an Http URI is it possible to read in the data into a DataTable (c#) without knowledge of the specification beforehand?

Comment: Did you try [ReadXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml(v=vs.110).aspx)?